# Oracle: Query to find if there is no pricing record for a particular quarter for a product

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a pricing table which has columns product, quarter and price. The data looks like below.

```
Product       Quarter  Price
    1         2019Q3   12.9
    1         2019Q1   5.9
    1         2018Q1   7.6
    2         2019Q2   2.2
    2         2019Q1   3.3
```

and so on....

I need to know which quarters of 2018 and 2019 each product does not have a record for.

So the output should be like this:

```
 Product          Missing_Quarters

    1             2019Q4,2019Q2,2018Q4,2018Q3,2018Q2
    2             2019Q4,2019Q3,2018Q4,2018Q3,2018Q2,2018Q1
```

Comment: Product  and Quarter are primary key in your pricing table, right? If not you must get the distinct values of those two columns as a first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cross join` to generate all values and then filter out the ones that exist:

```
select p.product, 
       listagg(yq.yq, ',') within group (order by yq.yq) as quarters_missing
from (select '2018Q1' as yq from dual union all
      select '2018Q2' as yq from dual union all
      select '2018Q3' as yq from dual union all
      select '2018Q4' as yq from dual union all
      select '2019Q1' as yq from dual union all
      select '2019Q2' as yq from dual union all
      select '2019Q3' as yq from dual union all
      select '2019Q4' as yq from dual
     ) yq cross join
     (select distinct product from pricings) p left join      
     pricings pr
     on pr.product = p.product and pr.quarter = yq.yq
where pr.product is null
group by p.product;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon for the quick response , however I am getting an error 'ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression'

Comment: @satej koli  use 'group by pr.product;' in the solution provided by Gordon

Comment: @RamSharma . . . Actually, the typo is in the `SELECT`, not the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thanks @RamSharma. Now it's giving another error :                                ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
01489. 00000 -  "result of string concatenation is too long"
*Cause:    String concatenation result is more than the maximum size.
*Action:   Make sure that the result is less than the maximum size.

Comment: @SatejKoli . . . Then you cannot directly do what you want.  Just select the values on separate rows.

Comment: @SatejKoli `ORA-01489` is extremely strange in your case. Replace the `LISTAGG` with `count(*)` and check the highest count value. You should not see more that 7 missing quarters per product in two years...

Comment: @MarmiteBomber , the data shown is just for example. I have a lot of data, but will select it in separate rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff , after correcting the typo ; it's working fine. The concatenation error has gone too. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case for [*partitioned outer join*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25555/tdpdw_sql.htm#TDPDW0072) that can "add" the missing key (quarter) for each partition (product_id)

The basic query which lists missing quarters for each product is as follows

```
SELECT p.PRODUCT, q.QUARTER
FROM   PRICINGS p
PARTITION BY (p.Product)
RIGHT OUTER JOIN QUARTER q
ON p.Quarter = q.Quarter
where p.QUARTER is NULL
order by 1,2 ;

   PRODUCT QUARTE
---------- ------
         1 2018Q2
         1 2018Q3
         1 2018Q4
         1 2019Q2
         1 2019Q4
         2 2018Q1
         2 2018Q2
         2 2018Q3
         2 2018Q4
         2 2019Q3
         2 2019Q4
```

The rest is as simple as [`LISTAGG`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) using the *descendant order of the quarters*

```
with q as
(
SELECT p.PRODUCT, q.QUARTER
FROM   PRICINGS p
PARTITION BY (p.Product)
RIGHT OUTER JOIN QUARTER q
ON p.Quarter = q.Quarter
where p.QUARTER is NULL)
select PRODUCT,
listagg(QUARTER,',') within group (order by QUARTER DESC) qlist
from q
group by PRODUCT


PRODUCT, QLIST
1   2019Q4,2019Q2,2018Q4,2018Q3,2018Q2
2   2019Q4,2019Q3,2018Q4,2018Q3,2018Q2,2018Q1
```

Note, that from performance reasons this way is preferred to the usage of *cross join* as you perform both joins in one step.

Comment: your answer helped a lot too. I wish I could select both answers as Accepted. Thanks a ton.